# Javascript - How to highlight the last clicked list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar list of items in HTML on a bootstrap page and i would like the last clicked item to be highlighted with a "active" class. I was wondering how i can get the whole list (ul) like an array so i could highlight a certain item (li) or highlight the last clicked item.

The list is structured like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar sidebar-style">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar sidebar-scrollable">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="jump(0)">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="jump(1)">Site 001</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="jump(2)">Site 002</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="jump(3)">Site 003</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="jump(4)">Site 004</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="jump(5)">Site 005</a></li>
```

What i need is some JS code which can set the last clicked li item to class="active" but still have the option to set any of the li items to the active one, for example if i wanted to have a random button and it selected item 4 then 2 etc. I guess the main thing i need is a way to have all list items like an array.

Comment: Where is your javascript? What does `jum()` do? StackOverflow is a place where you ask about a specific problem you are facing with your code and we try to help you, not a place where you ask for code and people write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use jQuery which is kind of simulating DOM manipulation like an array or more precisely an object.

My suggestion would be the following:

```
$(".nav-sidebar").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This code is removing the active class from all `li` items, and adding active class to currently clicked `li` item.

Cheers,

**Edit PS:**

You could also bind your event directly like this:

```
$(".nav-sidebar li").click(...);
```

But the purpose of using `.on()` is that it will bind the event dynamically, so that if you decide to add a new li to your `$(".nav-sidebar")` element, it will also trigger the event on that element.

**Edit:**

To answer @zeddex your question: How  to select manually li 4?
You simply use the following:

```
$("li:eq(3)").trigger('click');
```

That'll manually trigger a click event for li 4. If you want to select a specific li you can use a method of the like: `:eq(x)` in which `x` is the position of the li item you want to reach starting from `0` which corresponds to your first `li`. Have a look at jQuery DOC on that: [jQuery DOC on :eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thanks this works great for highlighting the last clicked item. How would i manually select li 4 etc though?

Comment: Voilà ! Updated my answer accordingly.:) Cheer !